# Lithium Access Control

Tags: lithium

I need to control who or what role gets access to what page or what method. Something like the class and method anotations on ASP MVC or Spring JAVA.

How can I do this in lithium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in complete ACL functionality on Lihtium's core, beauce there is no really solution to ACLs problem.

Hopefully, Lithium is kick-ass when it comes to deal with external libraries and plugin to extend the core functionality.

Take a look to [li3_access](https://github.com/tmaiaroto/li3_access) which is the most complete and flexible plugin or ACL out there, or [simpler](http://mysqltalk.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/i-wrote-a-new-acl-module-for-lithium-li3_simple_acl/) [solutions](http://www.lightcubesolutions.com/blog/?p=418).

If your only need is to specify which actions are public and which not, you can dot it using Lithium filters: Read the [guide](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/lithium-basics/filters.wiki)

PS: Zed Shaw - The ACL is Dead http://vimeo.com/2723800

Comment: For something very simple, just start with `Auth`: http://dev.lithify.me/drafts/source/en/06_auth/simple-authentication.wiki

Comment: Planning to update li3_simple_acl in the next couple weeks. I also got feedback from Jim Manico, a security expert from OWASP. He is writing a cheatsheet for ACL in the first quarter of this year. Some ACL considerations that prompted me to write my own: https://lists.owasp.org/pipermail/owasp-esapi/2008-July/000256.html 
"WE need to get away from the horror of referencing roles directly in code."