# Implementing User Authorization in PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, authorization

Assuming I have a valid session and an authenticated user, what are some ways to go about implementing user authorization in an application with a PHP/MySQL backend, and a heavy JavaScript front-end?

Most of the implementation examples I can find seem too focused on user authentication and the authorization just sort of happens.  For instance, an if statement checking if the type of user an admin.  This seems way too implemented to me.

In an implementation like mine, there is no way of knowing what "page" the user was on when they initiated the request.  So, a method of only serving certain content for certain users, determined by PHP, is too broad for what I need to do.

Ideally each entity has a sort of access control list based either on the user explicitly or what group or type the user is/in.

I went to a local bookstore and spent an afternoon looking through all they had on PHP, MySQL and JavaScript.  Surprisingly, most of the books had virtually nothing on user authorization.  That scares the hell out of me!  This has to be solved by anyone building a large web application that uses AJAX, I just can't seem to find something to get me started.

I would appreciate any and all feedback, experiences, tips, etc.  (Any books on this subject?)

Comment: Surely what you need is just an extension of the `checking if the type of user an admin` approach - you would have a `permissions` table with all your permission types as booleans, and the user table has an FK to a row in that table. Then before you output/do something you check whether the current user has the relevant permission.

Comment: A full ACL system has three dimensions of data- Users/groups, objects, and permissions. Objects is the largest, followed by users then permissions. Putting the largest number of tuples in a row keyed on the mid-sized vector is a recipe for an unscalable solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP security seems stuck in the dark ages of single password gives a token for a single user for a class of particular pages. You seem to be wanting to get a lot more fine-grained in your app, maybe even allowing access to specific pieces of resources depending on that login token. Your thought of access control lists is absolutely correct, and yes, you've discovered the dark secret: no one really published how to design or write an ACL mechanism. That said, it has been done.

First, are you familiar with [unix file permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Notation_of_traditional_Unix_permissions)? The're the `-rwxr-xr-x` things you see in an `ls -l` on the command line. Unix has chosen a very simplified approach to ACLs. Each person logged in has a User ID (UID) and one or more Group IDs (GID) (`whoami`, `groups`). The Unix file permissions allow three operations, `Read`, `Write`, and `Execute` which can be on or off. With 2^^9 states, these permissions easily fit in an integer, and Unix can then attach that 
integer to the file directly in the file system. When a user attempts to access a file, permissions are compared from strict to permissive, matching the most permissive privileges allowed. So, users get the first set of permissions, groups get the second, and anyone gets the third. Thus, an executable is usually 755: only the owner can change it, but anyone can read and use it.

Second, LDAP is the Lightweight Directory Access Protocol, a system designed to give multiple network users access to resources. OpenLDAP is a common Linux implementation, and Microsoft's Active Directory on Windows Server speaks LDAP (with a lot of extensions). LDAP has a much more robust system of ACLs. A general configuration is `access to [resources] by [who] [type of access granted] [control]` or `access to dn="uid=matt,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" by * none` to limit all access to to Matt's user information. For a much more complete discussion, I would highly recommend [Mastering LDAP](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/ldap/9781847191021), specifically chapter 4 on security. (This is where I get a bit out of my direct knowledge.) I am under the impression that LDAP stores this information in a separate database table, but I don't know that and can't find documentation one way or another. I am keeping an eye out for a possible schema for that.

Short stop to summarize: ACLs take a concept of a user token with possible groups above the user level, a collection of objects to secure in some way, and several consistent possible operations on those pieces- 3 dimensions of information. Unix stores two of those dimensions with the thing to be secured directly. OpenLDAP stores those three dimensions separately, in some way we don't quite know, but that I suspect is a linked tree structure.

Given that, let's take a look at how we could design an ACL system for a RESTful web application. For assumptions, we will break your application into discrete addressable units- each thing that needs to be secured will be accessible via a URI (`http://example.com/users`, `http://example.com/page_pieces/ticker`). Our users will be a simple UID/GIDs token- a user can be part of a several groups. Finally, our available operations will be based on the HTTP requests- GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc. We now need a system that efficiently handles a 3-dimensional array of data. Our schema should be pretty obvious: `(uri, userid, groupid, operations)`. We deliberately denormalize the `operations` column into a string list of `GET,POST,...` so we only need one table. There is no primary key, since we will never really be looking up by ID.

Queries will be done in two steps: `SELECT * FROM acl WHERE uri=@uri, userid=@userid` which will return 0 or 1 rows. If it returns 1 row, we're done and can grep `permisssion` to see if the operation is in the list (use * to indicate all perms). If we got 0 rows, run a second query `SELECT * FROM acl WHERE uri=@uri, userid='*', groupid in (@groupid)` which will again return 0 or some rows. If it returns some, loop through and look at perms. If it returns 0, do one last query `SELECT * FROM acl WHERE uri=@uri, userid='*', groupid='*'` which will finally return 0 or 1 row. If it returns 1, look at perms. If it returns 0, take the default action.

We can set permissions in several ways:

- `INSERT INTO acl VALUES (@uri, @userid, '', 'GET,POST')` allows a single user GET or POST access
- `INSERT INTO acl VALUES (@uri, '*', 'admin,contributors', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')`
- `INSERT INTO acl VALUES (@uri, '*', '*', '')` denies all access.

A couple things to note:

1. All URIs must be expressed exactly; this solution has no way to set
   default permissions at a higher level and have them trickle down
   (left as exercise to the Questioner).
2. Uniqueness of uri/uid/gid pairs should happen at some point. The app can handle it, or in MySQL you can do `ALTER TABLE acl ADD UNIQUE INDEX (uri, userid, groupid)` (look up documentation for similar constraints in other DBMSes).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are looking for something called Access Control List aka ACL ([which is dead](http://vimeo.com/2723800) according to Zed Shaw, great video).

It's pretty hard to give a you a solution without knowing what kind of backend you have, but you might check out how other are doing that.

For something specific to the lithium framework (PHP), see: [Lithium Access Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750604/lithium-access-control)

Comment: Great video!  Though not what I was looking for regarding my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I understand:

You need to build an access control list for your users? do you?
[correct me if I'm wrong]

I suggest you to create a DB table in which you can store the User ID (or username) and what kind of access it has on your Web Application. Then you can check the table to know if the requested URL/resource is accessible to that user. That's all.