# Implement different user level views in php

Tags: php, mysql, oop, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing User Authorization in PHP and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896835/implementing-user-authorization-in-php-and-javascript)

I have a basic accounting system with the following users and user levels,

**(User Name, Password, User Level)**

**A**, 123, *Admin*

**B**, 456, *Accountant*

**C**, 789, *Staff Member*

**D**, 999, *Manager*

I need to provide them with different selected information based on their user level. For example,

-only **admins** have privileges of creation and deletion of user accounts

-**staff** only has privileges to view sales and purchasing information

-only **accountants** have privileges to record accounting entries

-only **managers** and **accountants** have privileges to view management reports

How can i implement this using PHP(OOP)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many RBAC (role based access control) implementation already. I suggest using one of those rather than creating your own:

- http://phpmaster.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/
- http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/role-based-access-control.html
- [Role Based Access Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113543/role-based-access-control)